# charts_flutter: Different color for negative values in line chart

Tags: flutter, charts

This code:

```
Widget _chart(ctx) =>
    TimeSeriesChart(_data(),
        customSeriesRenderers: [
            LineRendererConfig(
                customRendererId: 'filled',
                includeArea: true,
            ),
        ],
    );

List<Series<Point, DateTime>> _data() =>
    [
        Series<Point, DateTime>(
            id: 'Data',
            colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
            data: store.data,
            domainFn: (Point p, _) => p.timestamp,
            measureFn: (Point p, _) => p.amount,
        )
            ..setAttribute(rendererIdKey, 'filled')
    ];
```

Produces this chart:

[image: Sample chart]

How do I make the negative filled area to be in different color e.g. red?

Bonus point if you can make the color to be in gradient (for both negative and positive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you still need it since the question is from 2019... As far as I know making it gradient is (still) not possible. However I think its possible to change the area color by changing the color of the line based on the value. Like this:

```dart
List<Series<Point, DateTime>> _data() =>
          [
              Series<Point, DateTime>(
                  id: 'Data',
                  colorFn: (Point p, _) { 
                    if(p.amount < 0 || p.amount == 0){ 
                      return MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault;
                    } else {
                      return MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault;
                    }
                  },
                  data: store.data,
                  domainFn: (Point p, _) => p.timestamp,
                  measureFn: (Point p, _) => p.amount,
              )
                  ..setAttribute(rendererIdKey, 'filled')
          ];
```

If the values goes from positive to negative, be sure to insert a fake 0 value. Since the lines are colored from point to point. Otherwhise you will see the blue line coming into the negative area.

Above works:
[image: screenshot area with two colors]